# Why classes designed for inheritance should rarely implement Serializble interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization

According to Effective Java :

> Classes designed for inheritance should rarely implement Serializable,
>   and interfaces should rarely extend it.

What is the reason behind this statement? In other words what would be the problems if they do  implement Serializable interface?

Comment: My memory might be rusty, but if I am right Josh Bloch explained the reasoning in the same item.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei No he doesn't.

Comment: I suppose it would imply that all classes which are inhering from this one can be serialized (which doesn't have to be necessarily true)

Comment: @Geek, but he does...  the same paragraph goes on to say _Violating this rule places a significant burden on anyone who extends the class or implements the interface..._

Comment: @Lucas What is the reason for this significant burden is the question.

Comment: @Geek, see answer below by Ziyao...  Everything he lists appears to be pasted right out of the book.

Comment: @Lucas you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next sentence in the same item says it:

> Classes designed for inheritance (Item 17) should rarely implement Serializable, and interfaces should rarely extend it. **Violating this rule places a significant burden on anyone who extends the class or implements the interface.** There are times when it is appropriate to violate the rule. For example, if a class or interface exists primarily to participate in a framework that requires all participants to implement Serializable, then it makes perfect sense for the class or interface to implement or extend Serializable.

Since I do not want Josh to be on my tail for infringing the copyright (as cool as that might be), I wouldn't copy all the item in this answer. Suffice to say the the reasoning for this is explained in the rest of the item.

EDIT: Josh listed a number of costs for implementing `Serializable`. If an interface / superclass implements it, the costs will be forced onto the extending classes.

> A major cost of implementing Serializable is that it decreases the
>   flexibility to change a class’s implementation once it has been
>   released. ...
>
> ...
>
> A second cost of implementing Serializable is that it increases the
>   likelihood of bugs and security holes. ...
>
> A third cost of implementing Serializable is that it increases the
>   testing burden associated with releasing a new version of a class.

Comment: how does the bolded line answer my question? Why violating this rule would place significant burden? I am looking for some explanation...

Comment: Because an implementing class then must make sure that any classes they use must be serializable or defined as transient.

Answer (score 7):

If a base class or interface implements Serializable, it forces every subclass or implementation, to fulfill the contract of the superclass or interface, to make sure that the subclass or implementation is also serializable.

That prevents any implementation to add fields that are non transient and not serializable to their implementation, for example.

Comment: +1 for the example of adding non serializable fields in the subclasses.

Comment: +1 but I must say that Bloch's given reasons don't make sense. There is no 'forces' about it: this 'significant burden' is only placed on future implementors *if the class is going to be serialized*, in which case the 'significant burden' is inescapable, and where exactly the `implements Serializable` is placed doesn't make the slightest difference to that.

Answer (score 0):

All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable as specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).So If you going to serialize a class designed for inheritance you should know whether all sub classes are needed to be serialized.Otherwise you can serialize the required sub classes only.